# Replace options of node-sass-chokidar to dart-sass

Tags: sass, node-sass, dart-sass

I have following script in package.json, using with node-sass-chokidar, tried multiple combinations but not working.
here is my current script:

```
build-scss": "npm run update-version && rimraf bundles/* && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o dist/css
```

and

```
"watch-scss": "npm run build-scss && node-sass-chokidar --watch ./src/ --recursive --include-path ./node_modules -o dist/css"
```

Want to replace the node-sass-chokidar with just, `sass` aka `dart-sass`.

Not able to figure out the right syntax, which can fulfil the existing requirements. I tried `--load-path` I tried the `input` : `output` syntax. no luck.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also trying to replace with node-sass-chokidar with sass and facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes- was:
    "build-scss": "npm run update-version && rimraf bundles/* && sass -I=node_modules src:dist/css",

and

    "watch-scss": "npm run build-scss && sass --watch ./src/:dist/css ./node_modules:dist/css",

Answer (score 9):

```
"build-css": "sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/ --watch",
```

This is working for me. Let me know if you guys have questions. Other packages for reference would be the following.

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"@types/react": "17.0.40",
"@types/react-dom": "17.0.13",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"sass": "1.49.9",
```

I think this is relevant to the above solution.