# replacing node-sass-chokidar with sass, Error: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: sass, node-sass-chokidar

Using the answer from this post [Replace options of node-sass-chokidar to dart-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480372/replace-options-of-node-sass-chokidar-to-dart-sass) to update our `build-css` and `watch-css` scripts in our react app. However, we are getting a new error that it is unable to find stylesheets:

```
nicholas@MacBook-Pro-4 client % npm start

> our-project@0.1.0 start
> npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js


> our-project@0.1.0 watch-css
> npm run build-css && sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/ --watch


> our-project@0.1.0 start-js
> react-scripts start


> our-project@0.1.0 build-css
> sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles/App.scss 2:9  root stylesheet
ERROR: "watch-css" exited with 65.
```

Here are the scripts in our **package.json**:

```
    "scripts": {
        "build-css": "sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/",
        "watch-css": "npm run build-css && sass -I ./src -I ./node_modules src/:src/ --watch",
        "start-js": "react-scripts start",
        "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
        "build": "react-scripts build --stats",
        "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer build/bundle-stats.json",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
```

In our `/client/src/styles` directory, we have App.scss, fonts.scss, tables.scss which are the 3 .scss files that our react app uses. I tried updating `src/:src/` to `src/styles/` however this did not work either, threw the same error. How can I correctly point to our 3 stylesheets in the /styles directory?

**Edit:** I followed the path and noticed in `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/` that `functions` did not exist. This import was happening in our `src/styles/App.scss` file

**src/styles/App.scss**

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';
...
```

[image]

There is an `_functions.scss`, however when I rename the import to include the _, unfortunately the original error `Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.` does not go away. Adding a `.scss` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the import in our `App.scss` file, which needed to be updated from `@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions'` to `@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions'`.

I am not sure why, previously, the path without the `../` was working. I am also not sure if/why the bootstrap/scss filenames were changed to include an _. Had I read the error messages more carefully initially I probably would have resolved this sooner.